# replace spaces with % in django or python app

Tags: python, mysql, django

im having a hard time fixing this one. i have a search function that will look for campaign name or campaign launcher name. for example if a user look for all campaigns launched by john doe. i want to enclose all spaces with '%' (%john%doe%) expected.

```
campaigns = Campaign.objects.filter(title(re.sub('/\s/g ', '%', search)) | launcher(re.sub('/\s/g ', '%', search)))
```

i also tried

```
campaigns = Campaign.objects.filter(title(re.sub(' ', '%', search)) | launcher(re.sub(' ', '%', search)))
```

but my code is not doing the right thing. im getting

```
`camp`.`name` LIKE '%john doe%' OR `user`.`name` LIKE '%john doe%'
```

and if i did the search.replace(" ", "%") im getting

```
`camp`.`name` LIKE '%john\\%doe%' OR `user`.`name` LIKE '%john\\%doe%'
```

i also got this sub function

```
def search_campaign(request, search):

def title(search):
    return Q(name__icontains=search)
def launcher(search):
    return Q(created_by_name__icontains=search)
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you search in django built in template tags and filters.?

Comment: im using django and reactjs for frontend

Comment: @MuhammedBilal why are you mentionning template stuff ??? This is about the ORM.

Comment: "NameError: global name 'title' is not defined". Did you mean "title=re.sub(....)" ?

Comment: sorry i updated my question post.

Comment: any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

search.replace(" ", "%") should work for input search = "john doe"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the query with `%` then simply below cod will work for you.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(" ", "%", " jhon doe ")
'%jhon%doe%'
```

If you want to send `title` like `%john%doe%` for " john doe " then this query should work.

```
campaigns = Campaign.objects.filter(title(re.sub(' ', '%', search)) | launcher(re.sub(' ', '%', search)))
```

Correct me if I got something wrong from the question.

Comment: this answer. did not work. the query return is LIKE "%john\\%doe%"

Comment: try some encode, decode. that may work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

"Regex" in python put spaces between words staring with capital letters.
for this first you need to import "re"

```
import re
def space(input):
 i1=re.findall("[a-z][A-Z]*",input)
 result=[]
 for word in i1:
  word=chr(ord(word[])+32)+word[1:]
  result.append(word)
  print(' '.join(result))
if __name__=="__main__":
 input="JohnDoe"
 space(input)
```